# Cor do texto em mala direta(gmail) já lido

Tags: html, css, email

Pelo gmail, quando recebemos um segundo email que tem o mesmo texto do anterior ele muda a cor do texto. Eu consigo manipular isso no html/css da mala direta, para que a cor do texto não seja alterada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido baseado no comentário: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19008979

Sugere colocar a cor hexadecimal com os 6 dígitos completos e as cores branco/preto como "quase" branco/preto (#FFFFFE e #000001).

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não.
Isso é funcionamento padrão do Gmail.
Mesmo que você envie um CSS que tente resolver esse problema, o CSS do Gmail irá sobrescrever o seu.

Comment: Depois de muito procurar, eu encontrei essa solução: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008054/font-color-different-from-original-design-email-newsletter
que fala pra colocar o texto como "quase" branco/preto e funcionou.